# Combining signals in MFCC space

Tags: convolution, mfcc

I'm looking at a data augmentation method for training up a neural network of speech data.  Currently I have two version of augmentation.

The first method works by taking an audio file and mixing in a set of noise files.

The second method works by convolving an audio file with another audio file to augment things like room responses and the like.

Once I have these combinations I then run them through my MFCC extractor and pass the MFCCs to the neural network training.

However this is very disk intensive with repeated loads of audio file.

What would be less disk intensive would be able to perform the combinations in memory.

Is there a way I can take 2 sets of MFCCs and combine them in such a way that I would get the same result as mixing or convolving the 2 base audio signals?

To put it another, way is it possible to convolve or mix signals in the MFCC space?

Comment: I am not sure about mixing (adding) two signals together, but convolution should be doable in case of MFCC's (in theory convolution translates to addition case of log-mel energies) - sort of like inverted CMN.

Comment: If your MFCC's downsampled, which is the only case that'd make it faster, then it loses invertibility, making the task impossible. Instead you could precompute MFCCs various combos of convolved inputs, at expense of disk space.

Comment: Is it possible to generate the augmented signals on-the-fly during training, as part of the processing pipeline? You don't have to store all of them on disk, or do you?

Comment: Thanks for the comments ... Its not really possible to calculate them on the fly due to the number of different combinations  available ... Was really just hoping there was some way to combine 2 sets of MFCCs to get the same result but it sounds like there isn't ... thats a shame ...